# How do I create hierarchies across dimensions?

Tags: ssas

I am using a snowflake design because I do not have huge volumes of data to worry about.

I have a Categories table and a Subcategories table and a Product table and from these tables I create a dimension with a

```
Category > Subcategory > Product
```

hierarchy.

I also have a Territory table, Country table, and a Customer table from which I create a dimension with a

```
Territory > Country > Customer
```

hierarchy.

This all works well, but what if I want to create other hierarchies, such as:

```
Territory > Country > Category > Subcategory > Product
```

or

```
Category > Customer > Product
```

or any other possible combination that the client wants to see.

I am unclear on how to do this with my existing table set.

Please ask for more information if I have not been clear.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible without making major changes in the cube design.
If you build an additional dimension which combines both dimensions into one.
You can achieve this. In this case you end up with 3 dimensions instead of 2.

To combine 2 dimensions, for each lowest level key combinations of both dimensions you need to create a new artificial key as the lowest key of the new dimension.
Then you can create the new attributes/hierarchies as usual.
Afterwards you can create a new unnatural hierarchy combining levels from unrelated hierarchies/attributes. This is what you want to achieve.
Since this new hierarchy will be unnatural, it will not perform very well but it will work.

Actually having 3 dimensions will not be necessary, after you combine 2 of them into a new one. You can get rid of the original 2 dimensions, since you can achieve the same functionality with the new one.